# Synchronize huge amount of data, separated in individual files to a mobile device

Tags: java, android, ios, performance, web-services

We have a quite big amount of data in form of thousands of `.MP4`, `.PDF` and `.JPEG` files (4 GB in total). Those are stored in our backend on a file-system and may change every couple days. We'd like to download everything to mobile devices for offline usage.

What would be the most time- and performance-efficient way to synchronise this data to a mobile device? What would be a suitable service look like for this approach?

We would like to consider a very stable solution, which can pick up at every point when the connection is lost or unstable.

We have discussed several solutions, like

- using a paging approach by combining multiple documents within a service call,
- streaming the data,
- zip the data on the server in multiple chunks and unzip it on the device,
- ... or simply go for thousands of HTTP request to download every document individually.

The mobile operating systems in question will be Android and iOS, the backend is Java. We fear that outdated device could have trouble with unzipping while having thousands of HTTP request may be slow through LTE as the handshake takes some time.

Is there a solution which solves all our concerns and provides good stability, high performance, reduced data-consumption (for non-wifi connections) and speed?

Comment: Do you users not have data caps on their cell connections? Syncing 4GB of data that changes regularly would cost users a lot of money in data usage in many parts of the world. Not to mention device storage space. Is this a good idea at all?

Comment: It will only be an option to the user and there will be a recommendation to switch to a wifi connection first. Some heavy mobile games do the same thing, they download the engine, textures & co. when first starting the app.